# How to remotely access mysql database from outside my network

Tags: mysql

sorry if this is a really basic question, but I am rather new to working with MySQL databases. Essentially I have created a database that I need to be accessible from outside my network (so I can have a company we are working with reference the data). I have set it up in a way that users on my network can connect to the database if they have the username, password and internal ip address of the database (10.1.10.10), but I cannot seem to get it to work for users outside of the network. Again, I apologize if this is simple I just have never had to do it before.

Comment: You must set up your router (which posesses between your net and Internet) for port mapping - all connections to its 3306 must be mapped to your workstation. Your router's WAN must be public ("white"). External clients may access your MySQL server while accessing WAN router's address.

Comment: what is not working?ie error message? There can be a lot of causes to this. To begin with a firewall issue: no open port, no port forward. Or a security in my SQL: the users arent created with % as host